# GUI for a Trivia game in java

Tags: java, swt

I am building a Trivia game in which there is a question and 4 possible answers desplayed.
I'm having trouble with setting each button such that if the correct answer is pressed- the user is added with 3 points, else- he get -1 points.
my main issue is with getting the text on the button so i can compare it with the saved data of the correct answer.

the relevant code is:

```
// create the answer buttons
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Button answerButton = new Button(questionPanel, SWT.PUSH | SWT.WRAP);
    answerButton.setText(answers.get(i));
    GridData answerLayoutData = GUIUtils.createFillGridData(1);
    answerLayoutData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    answerButton.setLayoutData(answerLayoutData);
    answerButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {}

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            if (.........#missing.........equals("correctAnswer")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Make the `Button` `final` and then use `answerButton.getText()` in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of your Buttons are anonymous. You cant access them later on. So you have to create a ArrayList and put your Buttons inside it.

Comment: it strictly said we should use listeners for that action.

Comment: Ok I see. To get the text from your button just simply use answerButton.getText().